# How to Display Table joins In WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I Have 2 Tables With countries and Visitors. I want to Show visitors with Country Names Using only Xaml maybe with converters too.
[Visitors Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sylff.jpg)
[How I want To display Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33LVF.jpg) I have Achieved This with Comboboxes but i want to display CountryNames in DataGridTextColumn.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a couple of possible solutions to get you started. 
You probably should give some more information about your model or example code of what you have so far, if you want some more specific advice.

---

- Binding to nested property

If your model allows you, then you could access the nested properties. You just target to it by using `.` *(dot)* delimiters in the binding.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VisitorName" Binding="{Binding VisitorName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country.CountryName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

- Binding to converted value

If you don't use nested complex types you can use a value converter.

```
public class MyCustomConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var myCountry = //Add your code to look up the country name linked to the given 'CountryId' (value) and return the name

        return myCountry != null ? myCountry.CountryName : string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Not needed with a OneWay binding
    }
}
```

You have to add the above converter as static resource and use it as followed.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VisitorName" Binding="{Binding VisitorName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding CountryId, Converter={StaticResource MyCustomConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can find another example of a converter [here](https://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

---

- Bind to a read only property

You could expand your model to have a read only property that gets this value. This is basically the same as the converter, but you have to edit your model.

```
public class Visitor
{
    public long Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string VisitorName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public long CountryId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string CountryNameString
    {
        get 
        {
            var myCountry = //Add your code to look up the country name linked to the given 'CountryId' (value) and return the name

            return myCountry != null ? myCountry.CountryName : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just connect to it with a binding. This is a `OneWay` ofcourse, unless you add some more customization and make it observable.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VisitorName" Binding="{Binding VisitorName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding CountryNameString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is XAML of your example...

```
 <Grid Background="Beige">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:PaymentViewModel></vm:PaymentViewModel>
        </Grid.DataContext>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">

        </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind for this is ...

```
 public partial class Payment : UserControl
    {
        public Payment()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... Create a List of objects.
            var Countries = new List<Country>();
            Countries.Add(new Country(1,"India"));
            Countries.Add(new Country(2, "USA"));
            Countries.Add(new Country(3, "Italy"));

            var Visitors = new List<Visitor>();
            Visitors.Add(new Visitor(1, "John Smiler",2));
            Visitors.Add(new Visitor(2, "Don Boscoi",3));
            Visitors.Add(new Visitor(3, "Smith Son",1));


            var GridList = from p in Countries
                        from r in Visitors
                           where r.CountryID == p.CountryID
                        select new { r.VisitorName, p.CountryName };

            // ... Assign ItemsSource of DataGrid.
            var grid = sender as DataGrid;
            grid.ItemsSource = GridList;
        }
    }
    public class Country
    {
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public Country(int countryid, string countryname )
        {
            this.CountryID = countryid;
            this.CountryName = countryname;
        }
    }
    public class Visitor
    {
        public int VisitorID { get; set; }
        public string VisitorName { get; set; }
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public Visitor(int visitorid, string visitorname, int countryid)
        {
            this.VisitorID = visitorid;
            this.VisitorName = visitorname;
            this.CountryID = countryid;
        }
    }        
 }
```

If you want to query against the database directly replace `DataGrid_Loaded` with the following:

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
    sqlConnection1.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Visitors.VisitorName,  Countries.CountryName FROM Visitors INNER JOIN Countries ON Visitors.CountryID = Countries.CountryID; ", sqlConnection1);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var DataSet = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(DataSet);

    var GridList = DataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList();

    // ... Assign ItemsSource of DataGrid.
    var grid = sender as DataGrid;
    grid.ItemsSource = GridList;
}
```